# Issue deploying Laravel backend with VueJS SPA frontend on ubuntu server

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I am new to setting up Laravel PHP framework as backend for my VueJs frontend project. Most of the examples i found online all used some Laravel specific deployment environment that directly brings the site online after cloning the repository files to the server which incase cant be applied or used much. The deployment server i use runs a ubuntu server with apache as the web server. I have copied the project files to the html folder on the server ,and virtualhost all been set. I can access the frontend without any issue on the production server. In nodejs usually i start the node backend server app and then can start using the website directly. I had set up the project setup following this site:

https://medium.com/@weehong/laravel-5-7-vue-vue-router-spa-5e07fd591981

I have integrated the pre-existing VueJs project into a new Laravel backend project as described on the above website. I am trying to deploy the project on Ubuntu server with apache as the web server.The backend php server app doesn't seem to start after placing the project files on the html folder. my .env file looks like below:

[image]

Update 1: 
my apache site config is :

[image]

Comment: Seems you apache config is wrong.

Laravel's index.php file is located under `{your-project}/public/index.php` 

So just pasting whole project in `html` will not work.

You can do trick just storing your project near `html` rename `html` to `_html` and then create symlink with name `html` which will be link to `{your-project-directory}/public`

Comment: Thanks for reply, you mean move remove whole project folder including the public subfolder to outside the html folder and create link in html folder for the project? should then apache config b changed to the new location too?